# How can I launch 10 instances, and tag them at once

Tags: ruby, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services

I want a single script that can lauch, and tag my instances which I can then use chef to configure them accordingly.

Say my service requires 10 instances, I want to be able to run 10 instances, then tag them according to their role (web, db, app server).

Then once I do that, I can use chef to connect to each one and configure them how i want.

**But I'm confused, I know I can launch instances, but how do you wait for them to come online?  Do you have to continously loop in some sort of a timer?**  That seems like a very hacky way to do it!

Answer (score 0):

If you're going to do everything from the outside you do just have to poll to wait for the instance to be ready (which doesn't necessarily mean its ready to use - actual startup completed a little later)

You can also pass user data when you start an instance. Most amis support cloud init, and will interpret the data passed as a shell script if in the right format. That shell script could run chef or do other configuration tasks.

Comment: Did you try? I expect the instance would have to be in the state running.